# How to find the variation function of $f$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $$f(x)=\sin x+\cos x$$

Then clearly $f$ is a function of bounded variation on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}].$ How to find the variation function of $f$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]?$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuously differentiable then the variation is given by $\int_0^x|f'|$.